# Hip-Hop Song Analysis

Tags: voice, time-signatures, analysis, musical-forms, texture

A friend and I are delving into some UK Hip-hop and have been listening to the much older songs and analyzing their style. I was wondering if anyone would want to help and provide their detailed input as well!

Heres the track:

Correct me if I'm wrong since I'm kind of new at this!

I've described the time/tempo as duple meter, 4 beats per bar about 95 bpm. Song starts with a dominant drum beat, followed by scratching turntables. We also hear a crescending “aaaaaaah-ya!' vocal extra throughout the song.

Voices: 3 rappers, saxophone, typical drum set (am i missing anything?)

The form of the song: would it be verse-chorus intro/AB/AB/outro or something else?

Musical texture: stricly homophony? or are there elements of other textures in there

Is there maybe a melodic contour to describe?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This sounds uncannily like what I wrote for my college music appreciation assignments

Comment: Although off-topic on the main site, this kind of question is perfect for [the chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/440/the-practice-room).